# ESP8266 cannot handle struct

Tags: esp8266

The following code works on a range of Arduino's but not on ESP. It returns random data for ID and Pin. The other two fields are always empty.

I use the Arduino IDE for both the ESP and the Arduino's. It looks like the ESP has it's own idea when it comes to struct.

```
#include <RH_ASK.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define BAUD 2000
#define RX 2
#define TX 5

RH_ASK driver(BAUD, RX, TX);

struct data {
  int id;
  int pin;
  int value1;
  int value2;
} myData;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Starting..");
    if (!driver.init())
         Serial.println("init failed");
}

void loop()
{
    uint8_t buf[RH_ASK_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN];
    uint8_t buflen = sizeof(buf);

    if (driver.recv(buf, &buflen)) {

      memcpy(&myData, buf, buflen);

      Serial.print("ID: "); 
      Serial.println(myData.id);

      Serial.print("Pin: "); 
      Serial.println(myData.pin);

      Serial.print("Value1: "); 
      Serial.println(myData.value1);

      Serial.print("Value2: "); 
      Serial.println(myData.value2);

      Serial.println("");
    }
    yield;
}
```

**Bad Data**

```
ID: 263145
Pin: 18350364
Value1: 0
Value2: 0
```

**Should be**

```
ID: 1001
Pin: 4
Value1: 267
Value2: 843
```

Comment: This looks like it's nothing to do with structs; this appears to be about the [RadioHead packet radio library](http://www.airspayce.com/mikem/arduino/RadioHead/) (which you never mention). When using a library you need to tell people what library you're using and give them an idea of what you're trying to do. I would also guess that you have some sort of hardware hooked up to pins 2 and 5 on the Arduino that you're keeping secret from us to make the question harder to answer.

Comment: try `short int` instead of `int` in the struct (looks like int's are 32bit in esp8266 and 16bit in arduino boards? perhaps? - *For portability use uint16_t and int16_t for ints* - https://github.com/mysensors/MySensors/issues/223

Comment: note: 263145 = **1001** + **4** * 65536

Comment: Awesome! You are my hero, I will dress like you when I go to comic-con Jaromanda X

Comment: Curt J. Sampson, thank you for your feedback, I will improve my questioning next time!

Comment: @Thijs - note: I seriously do look like Glen Quagmire :p

Comment: @Thijs - to be honest, there's nothing wrong with the question, the issue had nothing to do with the RadioHead packet radio library, nor anything to do with what's connected on pins 2 and 5 - in fact, that sort of information would distract from the actual problem as it is irrelevant to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that Arduino boards (8 bit ones at least), an `int` is 16 bits, where as the ESP's (8266 and 32) and possibly other non-arduino hardware, an int is 32bits

The safest way to declare structs in any case is to use variable types with known sizes, in your case, for signed 16bit ints

```
struct data {
  int16_t id;
  int16_t pin;
  int16_t value1;
  int16_t value2;
} myData;
```

or for unsigned 16bit ints

```
struct data {
  uint16_t id;
  uint16_t pin;
  uint16_t value1;
  uint16_t value2;
} myData;
```

Note: there's also `short int` which I believe is "guaranteed" to be 16bit (and "long int" is always 32 bit) - but having the bit size in the declaration is a far better (future proof) solution